# How to make expression evaluate more than once in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently, in my `$scope` for my controller, I have an attribute `$scope.disabled = true`.

In my HTML file, when I use `ng-disabled = {{disabled}}`, that element is initially disabled, however when I change `$scope.disabled = false`, `{{disabled}}` in `ng-disabled` isn't evaluated again. So how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it without `{{}}`(interpolation) would work.

```
ng-disabled="disabled"
```